# Вылетает приложение при парсинге Json файла

Tags: android

В папке assets лежит файл alphabet.json При парсинге почему-то не заполняется коллекция в которую я добавляю элементы из этого файла

```
public class AlphabetActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton btnBack;
    ImageButton btnPrev;
    ImageButton btnNext;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    List<Letter> data = new ArrayList<>();

    static final String TAG = "myLogs";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alphabet);

        new ParseTask().execute();

        AlphabetPagerAdapter mTextPagerAdapter = new AlphabetPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager(), getA());


        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.alphabetPager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mTextPagerAdapter);
    }

    private List<Letter> getA() {
        return data;
    }

    private class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String resultJson = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                InputStream in = getAssets().open("alphabet.json");
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                resultJson = buffer.toString();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            return resultJson;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            JSONObject jsonObject = null;

            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONArray alphabetArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("alphabet");

                for (int i = 0; i < alphabetArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = alphabetArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String letterSymbol = object.optString("letter");
                    String letterBigImage = object.optString("image_big");
                    String letterLittleImage = object.optString("image_little");
                    String letterDescription = object.optString("description");
                    String letterAudio = object.optString("audio");



                    data.add(new Letter(letterSymbol, letterBigImage, letterDescription, letterAudio));
                }
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот такая ошибка вылетает

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 0, found: 34 Pager id: ru.test.phone:id/alphabetPager Pager class: class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager Problematic adapter: class ru.test.phone.AlphabetPagerAdapter
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1167)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:687)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2271)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1358)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1607)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Коллекция не успевает заполнится что ли или почему так?

Answer (score 1):

После загрузки данных нужно вызывать `mTextPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` 
то есть данные в адаптере изменились, а оповещения об этом нет